# Bayesian estimation of ARMA coefficients

Tags: time-series, bayesian, arima, stan

It's clear to me how to find the parameters of an AR(p) process in a Bayesian setting. E.g., AR(2), we could do

$$ \alpha_1 \sim \mathcal{Normal}(0, 1)$$
$$ \alpha_2 \sim \mathcal{Normal}(0, 1)$$
$$ \sigma \sim |\mathcal{Normal}(0, 1)|$$
$$ \mu = \alpha_1 y_{t-1} + \alpha_2 y_{t-2} + \text{intercept} $$
$$ y \sim \mathcal{Normal}(\mu, \sigma) $$

This is then straightforward to implement in a probabilistic programming language, such as STAN.

Question is: what about the `MA` part of `ARMA`?

Looking at the formula on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average), it looks like I would need to add some terms like this to $\mu$:

$$ \mu = \alpha_1 y_{t-1} + \alpha_2 y_{t-2} + \theta_1 \epsilon_1 + \text{intercept} $$

where $\epsilon_1$ is an error term.

How would I include these terms into my model, such that I would run it in STAN?

Comment: The Stan User's Guide has a chapter on ARMA models. Here: https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_27/stan-users-guide/autoregressive-moving-average-models.html